# R.java having 2 members with same name layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, r.java-file

I may be asking a lame question but I am new to android and I cannot find the solution to this problem.

When I opened `R.java` file in my computer to know about how `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` works.

So I opened my R.java file and simply searched the key **layout** so I found 2 entries for that in my `R.java` file so I am confused that how can compiler recognize that which `layout` member I am currently trying to reference. I am putting the snippets of `R.java` file containing lines where `layout` member is declared.

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */

package com.myapp;

public final class R {
    public static final int layout=0x7f0100a9;
        /** <p>Must be a reference to another resource, in the form "<code>@[+][<i>package</i>:]<i>type</i>:<i>name</i></code>"
or to a theme attribute in the form "<code>?[<i>package</i>:][<i>type</i>:]<i>name</i></code>".
         */

     public static final class layout {
        public static final int abc_action_bar_title_item=0x7f040000;
        public static final int abc_action_bar_up_container=0x7f040001;
        public static final int abc_action_bar_view_list_nav_layout=0x7f040002;
        public static final int abc_action_menu_item_layout=0x7f040003;
        public static final int abc_action_menu_layout=0x7f040004;
        public static final int abc_action_mode_bar=0x7f040005;
        public static final int abc_action_mode_close_item_material=0x7f040006;
        public static final int abc_activity_chooser_view=0x7f040007;
        public static final int abc_activity_chooser_view_list_item=0x7f040008;
        public static final int abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material=0x7f040009;
        public static final int abc_alert_dialog_material=0x7f04000a;
        public static final int abc_dialog_title_material=0x7f04000b;
        public static final int abc_expanded_menu_layout=0x7f04000c;
        public static final int abc_list_menu_item_checkbox=0x7f04000d;
        public static final int abc_list_menu_item_icon=0x7f04000e;
        public static final int abc_list_menu_item_layout=0x7f04000f;
        public static final int abc_list_menu_item_radio=0x7f040010;
        public static final int abc_popup_menu_item_layout=0x7f040011;
        public static final int abc_screen_content_include=0x7f040012;
        public static final int abc_screen_simple=0x7f040013;
        public static final int abc_screen_simple_overlay_action_mode=0x7f040014;
        public static final int abc_screen_toolbar=0x7f040015;
        public static final int abc_search_dropdown_item_icons_2line=0x7f040016;
        public static final int abc_search_view=0x7f040017;
        public static final int abc_select_dialog_material=0x7f040018;
        public static final int activity_main=0x7f040019;
        public static final int notification_media_action=0x7f04001a;
        public static final int notification_media_cancel_action=0x7f04001b;
        public static final int notification_template_big_media=0x7f04001c;
        public static final int notification_template_big_media_narrow=0x7f04001d;
        public static final int notification_template_lines=0x7f04001e;
        public static final int notification_template_media=0x7f04001f;
        public static final int notification_template_part_chronometer=0x7f040020;
        public static final int notification_template_part_time=0x7f040021;
        public static final int select_dialog_item_material=0x7f040022;
        public static final int select_dialog_multichoice_material=0x7f040023;
        public static final int select_dialog_singlechoice_material=0x7f040024;
        public static final int support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item=0x7f040025;
    }
}
```

I wanna know that how compiler can resolve actual `layout` element while writing `setContentView(R.layout.acivity_main)` because there is an `int` variable and an inner class available with same name `layout`.

Comment: don't just -1 the question. I am new to this so it may be a very simple thing that I cannot understand but please answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>One is a `class`, the other is an `int`: there is no ambiguity from the context.</del>

When both interpretations are possible, it resolves to use the variable (not the Type):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        {
            Value x = new Value();
            // use the variable x
            System.out.println(x.i);
            // System.out.println(x.j); // does not compile
        }
        // use the type x
        System.out.println(x.i);
    }
}

class x {
    static int i = 42;
    static int j = 1;
}
class Value {
    int i = 100;
}
```

The output is:

```
100
42
```

**EDIT:** This is not what happens in your question.

You're right, there would be an ambiguity:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        // does not compile
        System.out.println(R.layout.x);
    }
}

class R {
    static final class layout {
        static int x = 42;
    };
    static final int layout = 25;
}
```

In fact, there is none because in the generated `R.java`, the `int layout` is in an innerclass:

```
public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
        public static final int layout = …;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        //…
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the responce but, if I write `R.layout` then which will be referenced because both are in the same class or is it the concept similar to late binding or overriding???

Comment: but even the class is written inside R class so the scenario is like class R contains 2 members 1) int member `layout`, 2) inner class `layout` so for those both, the context is same only which is `class R`

Comment: what if there is a case where `class X` has `int i` and `class i` as inner class inside of `class X`? What will be the case then?

Comment: I got my mistake the `layout` member was in a sepereate inner class so it won't generate any ambiguity, due to large amount of code I got that wrong.